# Linkedin auth asking permission to users each login in Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use Linkedin authentication in my asp.net mvc project. it's working correctly for the most of part but when users login with their Linkedin account, API asks for permission to users each login instead of asking once. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Note : I use Hammock libary for Linkedin authentication.

Thanks,

Comment: you have to give me details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization process with LinkedIn will result in an access token being returned to you that has to be used in conjunction with any future API calls.

LinkedIn's access tokens are currently valid for 60 days from the time of issue.

It sounds like your framework is not storing the access tokens against each of your users and re-using them on subsequent logins, so it has to re-authenticate them each time they log in to your application in order to get a new access token to use for that session.

Comment: This is a great point, but I don't believe it answers the question. The OP seems to be asking about users be asked for permissions again when reauthenticating, not when making subsequent calls after authenticating. When a user is logged out of your system, then authenticates again using OAuth, LinkedIn forces them to type in the password again (if it has been more than 30 minutes or so, it appears). Storing the token is necessary for when the user is already authenticated on your system and you make subsequent requests, but is not related to the case where the user reauthenticates.